# Find all row index numbers that have the same value in Python

Tags: python, list

Imagine 2 lists

```
x_test = [1, 3]
y_test = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

From this data I would like to make 2 new lists. The entries of the new lists shall be the row indexes of y_test, when their values = x_test(0) or x_test(1).

```
Desired Output:
z_1 = [0,1,6]
z_3 = [2,4]
```

How do I have to change my code in order to receive the desired output?

```
z_1 = []
for value in enumerate(x_test):
    if value in y_test == x_test[0]:
        z_1.append([index])
print(z_1)

z_3 = []
for value in enumerate(x_test):
    if value in y_test == x_test[1]:
        z_3.append([index])
print(z_1)
```

Comment: `index` is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate on `y_test` and compare the value with value in x : `value == x_test[0]`

```
z_1 = []
for index, value in enumerate(y_test):
    if value == x_test[0]:
        z_1.append(index)
print(z_1)
```

---

Generify

```
result = []
for xvalue in x_test:
    subresult = []
    for index, value in enumerate(y_test):
        if value == xvalue:
            subresult.append(index)
    result.append(subresult)
print(result)  # [[0, 1, 6], [2, 5]]
```

With list comprehension

```
result = [[i for i, v in enumerate(y_test) if v == xvalue]
          for xvalue in x_test]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach(using a for loop) seems fine but with a few mistakes (which are mentioned well by @azro). But you can also use list comprehensions:

```py
z_1 = [i for i,y in enumerate(y_test) if y == x_test[0]]
z_3 = [i for i,y in enumerate(y_test) if y == x_test[1]]
print(z_1)
print(z_3)
```

##### Output

```
[0, 1, 6]
[2, 5]
```

Note that, `z_3` should not result in `[2, 4]` as you mentioned. Rather it should be `[2, 5]`.